# How to derive the Black-scholes equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, finance

Assuming that $dS(t)=rS(t) \, dt+\sigma S(t) \, dW(t)$, and $dW(t)\sim N(0,\Delta t)$, and having a portfolio where $\Pi = C - \alpha S$ then the Black-scholes PDE is:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} +rS\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}-rC=0,$$

Which results from  setting:

$$\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}\right) \, \Delta t$$
equal to the bank rate of $\Delta\Pi = r\Pi\,\Delta t.$

My question is, is it ever the case that we do not set the second equation equal to $\Delta\Pi = r\Pi\,\Delta t$? How would that affect the Black-scholes pde? For example, what if $\Pi =C - P - \gamma S$?

Comment: Note the proper use of MathJax, as in my edits to the question: One writes $dW(t)\sim N(0,\Delta T)$ entirely within MathJax, not dW(t)~N(0,$\Delta $t). $\qquad$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question belongs on other site , like http://quant.stackexchange.com